# RFEM: Tensile force in member in buckling analysis

Tags: finite-element, stability

[image]

Here is a simple T-shaped structure in RFEM. The structure is loaded from above, into the intersection of all members.

I performed a buckling analysis, and obtained the buckling modes that I'm interested in. Looking at the results, the software claims that the horizontal members are in tension, and performs no calculation.

**Why would the horizontal members be in tension?** I see similar results in other structures too. I am mainly interested in the buckling load of the vertical member, so usually this is not a problem, but out of curiosity, why are the horizontal members supposedly in tension? They are definitely in bending, but why tension?

Here is the loading:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In finite element structural analysis codes, a buckling analysis is a two-step
process.

In the first step, a (usually) linear static analysis is performed to
calculate the stresses in your structure due to the applied loads. This step
is referred to as the pre-buckling analysis.

In the second step, these stresses are used to form the buckling matrix
(also called the geometric stiffness or tangent stiffness matrix). This buckling
matrix, along with the linear stiffness matrix, is used in an eigenvalue analysis
to calculate the critical loads for the structure. You multiply your actual applied
loads by the calculated eigenvalues to obtain the critical loads.

Often you are interested only in the lowest critical load. In the chart you are
showing in your post, the four lowest critical loads are shown.

For each of these eigenvalues, there is also an associated eigenvector. This is
the shape of the buckled structure associated with each critical load. The
table is also calculating some potentially-useful quantities for each member
for each of these buckling shapes (the eigenvectors). That is, the tensile forces
it is referring to in the table are *after* buckling has occurred.

What you were expecting to see were the forces (or stresses) from the
pre-buckling analysis. Most FEA codes provide an option to display these
forces and they are usually a very good check to verify that your model is
correct.

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't understand why tensile forces would occur. The vertical member is in compression, and the horizontal ones in bending. I don't see why this would change after or before buckling. Is the code performing some kind of post critical analysis behind the scenes?